# iText XMLWorker Compatibility chart

Tags: css, itext, xmlworker

I found a compatibility chart for CSS properties in iText's XMLWorker, and do not know how current this chart is. I'm currently working with iText version 5.5.5, but a chart for 5.5.9 would also be helpful if there are significant differences.

The one I'm using is here: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm

Comment: So, to clarify, you are asking if anyone is aware of an updated chart that applies to newer versions? If so, there is no indication on the chart itself (which, if you notice, is hosted on iText's website) of it being pegged to a specific version. I would assume then that this chart reflects the latest iText version.